# jQuery Tree issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi guys let me try to explain my problem:

I have 2 columns, on the left side i have a Tree list with jquery/CSS. on the right side i have a blank column.

When i select one node from the left side, i'm able to transfer this node to the right side, so this node do a cut/paste on the right side. I'm also able to remove the node on the right side back to left side, and here's the problem.

When the node return to the left, i need it to return on the same parent level it was before, not as the last node on left side.

My jquery used to transfer node is:

```
$("#move_right").click(function() {
        var users = $('#selected_users .innertxt2').size();
        var selected_users = $('#all_users .innertxt_bg').size();

        if (users + selected_users > 5) {
            alert('You can only chose maximum 5 users.');
            return;
        }

$("#move_left").click(function() {
        $('#selected_users .innertxt_bg').each(function() {
            var user_id = $(this).attr('userid');
            $('#select' + user_id).each(function() {this.checked = false;});

            var user_clone = $(this).clone(true);
            $(user_clone).removeClass('innertxt2');
            $(user_clone).removeClass('innertxt_bg');
            $(user_clone).addClass('innertxt');

            $('#all_users').append(user_clone);
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
```

A complete view its on jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/muzkle/LMbV3/1/

Please someone help me, thanks!

**EDITED**

Using the solutions by Zword, now i'm not removing the node from left side, now i have the ability to disable the checkbox to avoid duplicating on right side.

The problem is that after transfering to the right side, when i try to remove it (in case i've selected the wrong user) its not removing, i need to remove the selected user on right side and enable the checkbox again on left side. Also i noticed that when i select the users on left side to transfer to right side, its duplicating the last one added.

JsFiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/muzkle/LMbV3/3/

Comment: when you do all this und just de/select items. Why don't you just use one list at all? http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/LMbV3/4/

Comment: Hi Nico, i need 2 columns, like, its a system where you select the users for a job for example. so i need to check his name and transfer to the other side, there will not be a max select, the idea to "disable" checkbox its to avoid add duplicated user. So if i had add a wrong user, i need to be able to remove him from right side.

Comment: yes. But why do you need to transfer it at all? In my example you may select only two workers max an get their IDs. You know which users are active, so why transfer them anywhere?

Comment: Because there's a dropdown for "project select", after transfering to the right side, the users on the right side will be attached on database to that selected project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.insertBefore()` or `.insertAfter()` instead of append.

## insertBefore() : http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/

## insertAfter() : http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/

---

**OR**

---

Dont remove the element from the left side.Just hide it with `display:none;` and then just reshow it `display:block;/* or inline-block; */` when you want to make it visible.

---

## Update

```
$("#move_left").click(function() {
            $('#selected_users .innertxt2').each(function() {  /* on this line you were writing .innertxt_bg instead of .innertxt2 which is the actual class assigned to the righr side elements */
            var user_id = $(this).attr('userid');
            $('#select' + user_id).each(function() {this.checked = false;});
            
            var user_clone = $(this).clone(true);
            $(user_clone).removeClass('innertxt2');
            $(user_clone).removeClass('innertxt_bg');
            $(user_clone).addClass('innertxt');
            
            $('#all_users').append(user_clone);
            $(this).find('.selectit').attr("disabled","enabled");
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LMbV3/5/)

---

## Update2

I am adding the edited part of code along with fiddle:

```
    $("#move_right").click(function() {
        var users = $('#selected_users .innertxt2').size();
        var selected_users = $('#all_users .innertxt_bg').size();
        
        //if (users + selected_users > 5) {
            //alert('You can only chose maximum 5 users.');
            //return;
        //}
        
        $('#all_users .innertxt_bg').each(function() {
            if($(this).find('.selectit').is(':checked')){
            var user_id = $(this).attr('userid');
            $('#select' + user_id).each(function() {this.checked = false;});
            var user_clone = $(this).clone(true);
            $(user_clone).removeClass('innertxt');
            $(user_clone).removeClass('innertxt_bg');
            $(user_clone).addClass('innertxt2');
            
            $('#selected_users').append(user_clone);
            $(this).find('.selectit').attr("disabled","disabled");
            }
        });
    });
    
    $("#move_left").click(function() {
        $('#selected_users .innertxt2').each(function() {
            if($(this).find('.selectit').is(':checked')){
            var user_id = $(this).attr('userid');
            $('#select' + user_id).each(function() {this.checked = false;});
            
            var user_clone = $(this).clone(true);
            $(user_clone).removeClass('innertxt2');
            $(user_clone).removeClass('innertxt_bg');
            $(user_clone).addClass('innertxt');
            
            $('#all_users #select' + user_id).attr('disabled',false);
            $(this).remove();
            }
        });
    });
```

### [New Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DVG86/)

Comment: Hi mate, you're the best, solved my problem as i noticed that my client wants the left side to be intact. so i dont have to hide or remove anymore, just need to disable the checkbox and enable it again, but now i have another issue, i'm able to disable and enable it again, but when i click on left, it only enable the checkbox but dont remove the item on the right side :(

Comment: Ok Zword, just updated the jsfiddle with new clarification about the issue under "EDIT". thanks for helping me.

Comment: @WilliamXavier i added an update with the error pointed out with a comment in the code.Check the working fiddle

Comment: it works to remove, but its going again to the left side, i need to just remove it, and enable the checkbox for that user again on the left side.

Comment: Ok I will check your code.But will take time possibly tomorrow.Is it ok?

Comment: Yes no problem, like, now i got how to remove them completly, but its removing all of them, not the selected id, i'll continue checking and maybe i can get into a solution. Thanks a lot @Zword!

Comment: @WilliamXavier I was able to solve it fast and I have added a new fiddle with edited code.Check it

Comment: Thanks a lot @Zword, exactly as i needed it, Nico gave a solution as well, both are great, thanks :)

Comment: i have one request that i would like to have your help, i'm going to pay for your help through paypal, do you want it?

Comment: Sry no.I stay a bit busy nowadays becoz of my college project works.But I can alwys help you here on Stackoverflow anytime when free.Ask any question and just post me the link if you dont get an answer.

Comment: BTW tell me what help do you need?

Comment: Alright, thanks @Zword, i'll open it right now, i think its not something complicated, but for me that starting with jquery, its a world of codes :)

Comment: Hi @Zword, here's the new question. thanks for helping :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22749513/jquery-tree-issue-add-first-child-li

Comment: yeah, you're the only one who can save me here haha

Answer (score 1):

You have posted new information, that you just needed a add / remove function for your list, without the need to transfer it between left and right. Here is a different approach:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/LMbV3/6/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var maxAllowed = 2;
    var $selectTable = $("#mytable");
    var $selectList = $("#selected_users ul")
    $("#max-count").html(maxAllowed);

    var getActivated = function () {
        var activated = new Array();
        $selectTable.find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').closest("li").each(function () {
            var $obj = new Object;
            var currentBox = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]');
            $obj.id = currentBox.val();
            $obj.boxid = currentBox.attr("id");
            $obj.name = $(this).find("label").text();
            activated.push($obj);
        });

        return activated;
    }

    var updateActiveList = function () {
        // Truncate list
        $selectList.html("");
        $(getActivated()).each(function () {
            $selectList.append("<li>" + this.name + ' <a href="#" class="remove" data-id="' + this.id + '" data-box-id="' + this.boxid + '">x</a>' + "</li>");
        });
    }

    var countActivated = function () {
        return getActivated().length;
    }

    $('#view').click(function () {
        allIds = new Array();
        getActivated().each(function () {
            allIds.push($(this).attr("id"));
        });
        alert(allIds);
    });

    $selectList.on("click", "a.remove", function () {
        $('#' + $(this).data("box-id")).prop("checked", false);
        updateActiveList();
    });

    $selectTable.on("change", 'input[type="checkbox"]', function (event) {
        if ($(this).is(":checked") && countActivated() > maxAllowed) {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log("max reached!");
            $(this).prop("checked", false);
        }
        updateActiveList();

    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="stack">
    <div class="form_top"></div>
    <div class="float_break"></div>
    <div class="form">
        <br />
        <div class="formbox">
             <h5>All Users</h5>
            <br />
            <div id="all_users">
                <!--<ul id="user1" userid="1" class="innertxt">
                        <li>
                            <li><input type="checkbox" id="select1" value="1" class="selectit" /><label for="select1">Name: William</label></li>
                        </li>
                 </ul>-->
                <div id="mytable">
                    <ul data-depth="0" class="collapse level0">
                        <li><span class="toggle collapse"></span>Item 1</li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul data-depth="1" class="collapse level1">
                        <li><span class="toggle"></span>Item 2</li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul data-depth="2" class="collapse level2" id="user1" userid="1">
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="select1" value="1" class="selectit" />
                            <label for="select1">William</label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul data-depth="2" class="collapse level2" id="user2" userid="2">
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="select2" value="2" class="selectit" />
                            <label for="select2">João</label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul data-depth="0" class="collapse collapsable level0">
                        <li><span class="toggle collapse"></span>Item 5</li>
                    </ul>
                    <ul data-depth="1" class="collapse collapsable level1" id="user3" userid="3">
                        <li>
                            <input type="checkbox" id="select3" value="3" class="selectit" />
                            <label for="select3">João</label>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="float_break"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="selected_users">
                <ul></ul>
            </div>
            <div class="float_break"></div>
            <div style="float:right; padding:5px 160px 0 0">
                 <h6>Select maximum <span id="max-count"></span>.</h6>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="float_break"></div>
        <div class="formbox">
            <input type="button" value="View Selected users Id" id="view" class="form_button" />
            <div class="float_break"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form_bot"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow Nico, exactly what i need, but its there a way to make it working with the "right and left" buttons? Like i select and click right button. that's just because that's the way the client wants it, he said its more user friendly to understand hoe to add users. thanks mate

Comment: yes there surely is a way. But you will have to find it on your own and use this as a help. But i still think this is more user friendly than the left, right buttons. You can either uncheck the checkbox to remove a user or just click the x next to the name on the right side. With multiple checkboxes you will get in trouble with duplicated Ids (when you clone the checkbox) etc. etc. Try to educate your customer ;)

Comment: Hi @Nico, is there a way you can help me with something?