# jQuery Tree issue - add first child li

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 columns, on the left side a team with users, on the right column, will be displayed the users i have selected. so everything its working but i'm trying to implement a new feature as follow:

I have 2 list level like a tree (only 2 levels). When i click on a user, i'm able to select it sending to the right column. Also, when i click (single click) on the first level (team name), the second level (users) appear as toggle jquery function. i need so, when i double click on a team (level 1) all users on that tree turns selected and go to column on the right side.

Also, when i click on the team (first level) on the right side, all the users get removed back.

My code to add the users jquery current is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var maxAllowed = 10000;
var $selectTable = $("#mytable");
var $selectList = $("#selected_users ul")
$("#max-count").html(maxAllowed);

var getActivated = function () {
    var activated = new Array();
    $selectTable.find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').closest("li").each(function () {
        var $obj = new Object;
        var currentBox = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]');
        $obj.id = currentBox.val();
        $obj.boxid = currentBox.attr("id");
        $obj.name = $(this).find("label").text();
        activated.push($obj);
    });

    return activated;
}

var updateActiveList = function () {
    // Truncate list
    $selectList.html("");
    $(getActivated()).each(function () {
        $selectList.append("<li><a href='#' class='remove' data-id='" + this.id + "' data-box-id='" + this.boxid + "'>" + this.name + "</li></a>");
    });
}

var countActivated = function () {
    return getActivated().length;
}

$('#view').click(function () {
    allIds = new Array();
    getActivated().each(function () {
        allIds.push($(this).attr("id"));
    });
    alert(allIds);
});

$selectList.on("click", "a.remove", function () {
    $('#' + $(this).data("box-id")).prop("checked", false);
    updateActiveList();
});

$selectTable.on("change", 'input[type="checkbox"]', function (event) {
    if ($(this).is(":checked") && countActivated() > maxAllowed) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("max reached!");
        $(this).prop("checked", false);
    }
    updateActiveList();

});
});
```

Here's a jsFiddle with working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/muzkle/LMbV3/7/

Thanks all!

**EDIT**

Hi, i just added a code to separate single click from double click. So when the user single click, will open the tree. now i need when the user double click on the first level, add both (first level and they're childrens to the right side.

Follow code for single and double clicks:

```
alreadyclicked=false;
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#mytable').on('click', '.toggle', function (ul) {
                    //Gets all <tr>'s  of greater depth
    //below element in the table
    var findChildren = function (ul) {
        var depth = ul.data('depth');
        return ul.nextUntil($('ul').filter(function () {
            return $(this).data('depth') <= depth;
        }));
    };

    var el = $(this);
    var ul = el.closest('ul'); //Get <tr> parent of toggle button
    var children = findChildren(ul);
    var el=$(this);
    if (alreadyclicked){
        alreadyclicked=false; // reset

        clearTimeout(alreadyclickedTimeout); // prevent this from happening


    }else{
        alreadyclicked=true;

        alreadyclickedTimeout=setTimeout(function(){
            alreadyclicked=false; // reset when it happens


    //Remove already collapsed nodes from children so that we don't
    //make them visible. 
    //(Confused? Remove this code and close Item 2, close Item 1 
    //then open Item 1 again, then you will understand)
    var subnodes = children.filter('.expand');
    subnodes.each(function () {
        var subnode = $(this);
        var subnodeChildren = findChildren(subnode);
        children = children.not(subnodeChildren);
    });

    //Change icon and hide/show children
    if (ul.hasClass('collapse')) {
        ul.removeClass('collapse').addClass('expand');
        children.hide();
    } else {
        ul.removeClass('expand').addClass('collapse');
        children.show();
    }
    return children;

            // do what needs to happen on single click. 
            // use el instead of $(this) because $(this) is 
            // no longer the element
        },300); // <-- dblclick tolerance here
    }
    return false;
});
});
```

And new jsFiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/muzkle/LMbV3/8/

Comment: Edited the code to use Single and Double click events on single element. Now i just need to understand how to double click and select the whole tree and send to the right side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To distinguish different groups I am **wrapping each group/section in a wrapper div with class `.wrapper`**

```
<div class="wrapper">
.
.
</div>
```

Also I attached a double click event to `.wrapper` and currently I have made it to **alert** its inner labels.Just write some additional code to add these labels to the right side like you are currently adding one element on click.Below is the code with **jQuery .dblclick() function** which attaches a double-click event to `.wrapper`.

```
$('.wrapper').dblclick(function(){
    $(this).find('label').each(function(){
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

### [Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eE33k/)